# How do I change color in <kbd>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to change color in `<kbd>`?

Here is my code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><kbd><?php echo $x; ?></kbd></a>
```

Comment: here is my code: <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><kbd><?php echo $x; ?></kbd></a>

Comment: Are you trying to change the way that code is rendered in a web browser? What does Sublime Text 3 have to do with anythong? Or SQL? Or PHP for that matter?

Comment: i just want to change the background color for the kbd because it has a color black for the default background

Comment: …so, that's a yes? You do want to change the way this is rendered in a web browser? Have you learned about CSS yet?

Comment: i learned CSS a little bit but i'm not good enough to perfect my coding skills i'm still learning, yes i want to change it can you give me an idea on how to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to change the colors of the `<kbd>` element:

```
.navbar-brand kbd {
  background-color: lightblue;  // Changes background color
  color: #333;                  // Changes text color
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For further reference and as there's [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) tag in OP question, I think the proper way to do this is using [Bootstrap Helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes) that are *already loaded*.

- To change color, use [Contextual colors](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-colors)
- To change background, use [Contextual backgrounds](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds)
- To change all according, use [Labels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) or [Alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) <sup>*(but without the `label/alert` class as you're in `kbd`)*</sup>

[image: demo]

> *See the following code snippet for live example.*

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3>Default, no class</h3>
<kbd>default</kbd>
<hr />
<h3>Only background</h3>
<kbd class="bg-muted">bg-muted</kbd>
<kbd class="bg-primary">bg-primary</kbd>
<kbd class="bg-success">bg-success</kbd>
<kbd class="bg-info">bg-info</kbd>
<kbd class="bg-warning">bg-warning</kbd>
<kbd class="bg-danger">bg-danger</kbd>
<hr />
<h3>Only text</h3>
<kbd class="text-muted">text-muted</kbd>
<kbd class="text-primary">text-primary</kbd>
<kbd class="text-success">text-success</kbd>
<kbd class="text-info">text-info</kbd>
<kbd class="text-warning">text-warning</kbd>
<kbd class="text-danger">text-danger</kbd>
<hr />
<h3>All (with label)</h3>
<kbd class="label-default">Default</kbd>
<kbd class="label-primary">Primary</kbd>
<kbd class="label-success">Success</kbd>
<kbd class="label-info">Info</kbd>
<kbd class="label-warning">Warning</kbd>
<kbd class="label-danger">Danger</kbd>
<hr /><h3>All (with alert)</h3>
<kbd class="alert-muted">alert-muted</kbd>
<kbd class="alert-primary">alert-primary</kbd>
<kbd class="alert-success">alert-success</kbd>
<kbd class="alert-info">alert-info</kbd>
<kbd class="alert-warning">alert-warning</kbd>
<kbd class="alert-danger">alert-danger</kbd>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to add class in `<kbd>` tag. Using that, you can directly access `<kbd>` tag.

```
.navbar-brand {
  background-color: lightblue;  // Changes background color
  color: #333;                  // Changes text color
}
```

html code is

```
<a href="#"><kbd  class="navbar-brand"><?php echo $x; ?></kbd></a>
```